# Horizontal scroll view image size

Tags: android, image, horizontal-scrolling

How can i show only two images at a time in horizontal scroll view. on swiping the screen it will show next two images.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for `ViewPager`. See [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html) for more information.